# SmartSVN: How do find your SVN URL and copy it?

Tags: svn, smartsvn

Is there any easy way to copy the SVN url? I deal with dozens of projects at once and I don't care to memorize paths. I can see the URL's at the bottom of the SmartSVN window -- not selectable text. I can also hover over the root folder in the Directories pane and see the URL details, also NOT selectable text. I can also see non-selectable text in the log window. All useless for copy/paste

Is there any way to get the URL again shy to finding it from the history of checkout -- which just seems fragile/wrong.

**ANSWER: you can only do this with "pro" version only, lol. Best choice is to use a PC and TortoiseSVN for a great full featured app that does not cost $.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit|Copy URL** is present in the main window, as well as the repository browser.

Comment: @user1836553 This is not a joke that **Copy URL** is available only in paid version, right?

Comment: @bahrep, this is correct, copy url is only for the pro version. But there is a work around, If you "Checkout" again, you can see the previous history and chances are your older URLs are still among the undead checkout history, lol.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without pro version: press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (show log) on a file, and there you will be able to copy the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If not using a pro-version, click on the 'window' tab, and select 'New Repository Browser' all your recent repository URLs will appear in the dropdown.
I'm unsure if the repository URL can be located in the pro-version through the same options.